# End Reverse SSH session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access, raspberry-pi

I've got 20 or so machines scattered around the country (RPi's) and they are all on mobile networks (don't have a public IP.) Occasionally, I need to get access to a machine, so I've set up a rescue script that the machine will try to pull down every so often, and I can have that script do a reverse SSH onto my server so I can log in to it.  This is working well, but I'm trying to figure out how / where I can kill that session.

Basically, I want to run the same script on all machines (they won't all run at the same time, and they pull down only their specific script anyway).  So I want them to connect to my server, where I can then access them by doing something like:

```
ssh -p 2222 pi@localhost
```

But even after I connect and exit, this connection persists, which I assume will cause problems for another machine trying to connect as well.  I don't want to give each machine its own port number, so I need to figure out how to kill that reverse SSH session.  Not sure if it has to be done on the Pi, or on my server.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's the command you're using on the remote machines to open the SSH tunnel?  I'm guessing the easiest way to close the tunnel will be to do a `ps | grep <port_forwarded>` on the remote machine and then kill that PID.

Comment: If i'm SSH'd directly into the machine (I have a test machine locally) and I run ps, I can see ssh running.  However if from the server I ssh into the open tunnel and run ps, I don't see SSH running, therefore have nothing to kill.

Comment: Sorry, my ps command probably should have been something like `ps aux` or something that would list all the ssh sessions (and running processes).  I'm guessing the user you log in as is different than the user that initiated the tunnel?

Comment: What I've got working now, and I guess this is the easiest way to do it, is from the server, after having connected via the command above, I run kill $(pidof ssh) and that ends the sessions and frees up the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by doing this:

```
kill $(pidof ssh)
```

Comment: This will kill all opened sessions, not just the current one. I guess this is fine in your case. Here I can see a `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable which both seem to contain the ssh port of the corresponding session. With the help of `netstat` or `lsof` they could be used to identify the exact PID of the current session.

Comment: Good point, but you're right that in my particular case, with only 1 connection at a time this will work.  Thanks for the heads up though, perhaps if I get some time I'll work on figuring out more specific solution.